# Get the input type of a textbox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textbox, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for which I am trying to listen to the mouse clicks using message passing.

I want to know if it is possible to obtain the input type of a textbox when a mouse ic clicked on the textbox ?

Comment: Are you talking about `<textarea>`'s, `<input type="text"/>`'s, or both?

Comment: Are you looking for what is in the `input`'s `type` attribute?

Answer (score 6):

The type of the input is a property on the element.

For example, you can open chrome inspector on this page and type in the console:

```
var firstInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
firstInput.type; // outputs "text"
```

edit: you could bind the click on these elements and get the type from the `event.target` property of the event.

Comment: I used jQuery once but it stole my coffee. :-(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CcKP5/1/ now with more `jQuery`. in Chrome *13.0.782.24*, the only one that doesn't work is `type="color"`.  The `type="range"` input works if you slide the slider around.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you having trouble with?

If you have the input element you can just do:

```
theinputelement.getAttribute(type);
```

**Update:**

Okay, here's how you would get click events and find out the type of the input element with jQuery:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (event.which !== 1) {
    return;
  }
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    alert(event.target.type);
  }
});
```

Comment: the trouble is that, I am given a random website containing textboxes; now whenever I click on the textbox, I need to obtain the input type of the textbox. I dont have any input element

Comment: Added an example using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

have your onclick handler take an arg, and pass the object:

```
<script>
 function handler(object) {
  alert(object);
 }
</script>
<div onclick="handler(this);">this is a test</div>
```